# Is this group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_k$? The integers with multiples of $k$ subtracted until you're under $r$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

Where as the elements of the ring of integers modulo $n$ can be found by taking the integers and subtracting multiples of $n$ until you're just under $n$, consider the structure formed by taking integers and subtracting multiples of $k$ until you're just under $r$, for $r-k\lt k\lt r$.  Then $k$ becomes additive identity, the elements can be labeled $r-k...r-1$. Does this structure also form a group under addition defined by adding the elements included into $\mathbb{Z}$ and then subtracting multiples of $k$ until you're under $r$?  Is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_k$ ?

The set seems to be generated cyclically:

$$k+1, k+2,...,k+(r-k-1), \\k + r-k = r = r-k, \\r-k+1,...,\\r-k+(k-(r-k))=r-k +(2k-r)=k$$

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly, you are simply taking a different coset representative for the map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_k$. Does that make sense, or do you need a fuller explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $\mathbb{Z}/ k \mathbb{Z}$ is given by equivalence classes of elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ where the equivalence relation is $a \sim b$ when $a-b \in k \mathbb{Z}$. So for instance, if $k=3$, the group has 3 elements corresponding to $0+ 3\mathbb{Z}, 1+ 3\mathbb{Z}, 2+ 3\mathbb{Z}$ which we can denote $[0], [1], [2]$. What you've observed, is that there is no reason we have to identify the equivalence class $i+ k \mathbb{Z}$ with the element $i$, since we have $(i+nk)+ k \mathbb{Z}=i + k\mathbb{Z}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. In particular, if $r$ is some integer, then you can pick the $k$ representatives $r-1, ..., r-k$ and each representative will correspond to a particular equivalence class in $\mathbb{Z}/ k \mathbb{Z}$. Each choice of representatives will give you a different notion of addition (as you've noted) but each choice will yield a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/ k \mathbb{Z}$ given by the isomorphism: $x$ maps to the equivalence class $x+ k\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: On the last sentence do you mean $x + k\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Yep! Thanks for pointing that out.